# Tooltip only when mouse is directly over MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I have tooltips for MenuItems in a ContextMenu that only appear when the mouse is over the actual MenuItem, not its popup submenu? Preferably without having to set properties or style for every item in the submenu.

```
    <Button Content="Push">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem ToolTip="ToolTip" Header="Want ToolTip Here" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="5000">
                    <MenuItem Header="Do Not Want ToolTip Here"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Or Here"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Or Here"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue: If I right-click on the button, let the submenu open and move the mouse to one of the subitems, the tooltip still appears 5 seconds after I moved the mouse over the main menu item.

[image: ToolTip Trouble]

Comment: Have you tried setting the tooltip of the subitems to "" so that there is no tooltip to display?

Comment: If I set the tooltips to "", then the tooltip appears as a small box with no text - definitely not a good option. And as I wrote in my question, I would much prefer a solution that does not require setting properties on every subitem.

Comment: You can always set it as ToolTip="{x:Null}"

Comment: Setting it to Null means there is no tooltip - that is the default - and it will thus still display the parent MenuItem's tooltip.

Comment: On which item do you have the ContextMenu, just tested on label and button, it's not like you describe it. ToolTip is only popping up on the main MenuItem and not the below ones.

Comment: It happens for me on button; I added a screenshot to illustrate. That's using .NET Framework 4.5.2 and Visual Studio 2017; it's the same for .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just register `ToolTipOpening` event with the event handler in below.

```
private void MenuItem_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(element);

    if (p.X < 0 || p.X > element.ActualWidth || p.Y < 0 || p.Y > element.ActualHeight)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an ideal solution, as it requires code behind, but it does the trick - thanks!

Comment: I think there isn't a only xaml solution in this case. WPF manager all the popup in framework level, so you can use it by follow its rules or you have to implement your own popup service. In both way, you can't avoid writing codes. And also, code behind is not awful, if you use it to handler only view's business and use it only when it's necessary.